# Can't login in admin panel with superuser or with normal users with custom User Model

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I created a AbstractUser model in Django which adds some custom fields, but now whenever I create a user (whether by calling User.create_user() or with python manage.py createsuperuser), the user is created fine with a hashed password, but I cannot use the password to login. When I try to login on the admin console, I get "Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive." I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going wrong since in my database, the correct username + a hashed password appear when I create a user.

This is my user Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, username, password, avg_recipe_rating=None, num_ratings_received=0, num_recipes_created=0):
        user = self.model(username=username)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.num_ratings_received=num_ratings_received
        user.num_recipes_created=num_recipes_created
        user.avg_recipe_rating=avg_recipe_rating
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self,username, password, avg_recipe_rating=None, num_ratings_received=0, num_recipes_created=0):
        return self._create_user(username, password, avg_recipe_rating, num_ratings_received, num_recipes_created)

    def create_superuser(self,username, password, avg_recipe_rating=None, num_ratings_received=0, num_recipes_created=0):
        return self._create_user(username, password, avg_recipe_rating, num_ratings_received, num_recipes_created)

class User(AbstractUser):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    avg_recipe_rating = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    num_ratings_received = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    num_recipes_created = models.IntegerField()

    last_login = None
    groups = None
    user_permissions = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    email = None
    date_joined = None

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_superuser(self):
        return True

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'SampleUser'
```

Comment: Have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings? Also this appears to be a very weird implementation? You are setting all users as staff / superusers, removing basic fields one would consider important...

Comment: I have set AUTH_USER_MODEL. I realize it’s a bit weird but I already had a database with a User table and I wanted to also use the Django User functionality like hashing passwords so that’s why I removed fields like last_login that weren’t in my database’a user table.

 I set every user to be a superuser because I don’t care about the superuser distinction and I thought maybe the admin dashboard logins weren’t working because the users weren’t superusers but that didn’t fix the issue.

Comment: Could you add your **AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS** settings ?

Comment: I am not using an Authentication Backend